# Amazon SES dailyl limit query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We will be in some top press tomorrow, and AWS simple e-mail service's  daily limit is critical bottleneck for us.

Bit lost on whom to contact, any heads up ?

appreciate a small e-mail note on raxitsheth2000@gmail.com

Raxit Sheth

Comment: You might want to switch to another provider like SendGrid, Postmark, etc. for the short term.

Answer (score 3):

**Contact Amazon?**!

[At least thats what they say...](http://aws.amazon.com/en/ses/)

> If you need to send more volume per day than your current sending quota, please contact [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest) and we will evaluate your request promptly.